# Can't edit permission JSON on AWS, despite it telling me I can

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-permissions

I am hoping to set a time limit on AWS permissions for my users.

But I cannot edit the policy JSON file, despite it saying I can:

[image]

Note the line `You can still view or edit the JSON policy document.`

But then it says read-only. Is there a way to download the JSON, edit it, then upload it?

Or is there another way to put a time limit on user permissions?

Comment: What time limit? Do you have proper permissions to manage permissions? The blue info box is unrelated to any permissions you may have or not have, it only references the inability to render the policy as "policy summary", nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @luk2302 No, it does not "only" reference the inability to render the policy. Read it. It also says "you can still view or edit the policy document." Also, I have full root access to this AWS account.

Comment: I know what it says - I am telling you it does *mean* EXACTLY what my comment says, regardless of what it’s English meaning would be or what you think it means. It simply is not phrased properly - is is often the case with AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that you are trying to modify "AWS managed" policy (you can see the small aws logo before the policy name) and that is not possible. You can create a new policy (will get a tag "customer-managed") and then you can copy/modify permissions

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.